# Meteor: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation (websocket)

Tags: meteor, websocket, openshift

I have a website that uses Meteor 0.9. I have deployed this website on OpenShift (http://www.truthpecker.com).

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I go to a path on my site (/discover), then sometimes (though not always), the data needed are not fetched by Meteor. Instead I get the following errors:

On the client side:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.truthpecker.com/sockjs/796/3tfowlag/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

And on the server side:

```
Exception from sub rD8cj6FGa6bpTDivh Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation
    at checkSubtree (packages/check/match.js:222)
    at check (packages/check/match.js:21)
     at _.extend._getFindOptions (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:216)
    at _.extend.find (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:236)
    at Meteor.publish.Activities.find.user [as _handler] (app/server/publications.js:41:19)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1492)
    at _.extend._runHandler (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:914)
    at _.extend._startSubscription (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:764)
    at _.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:577)
    at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:541
Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
```

Can anyone help me to eliminate this error and get the site working? I'd be very grateful!

Tony

P.S.: I never got this error using localhost.

EDIT:

The line causing the problem the problem is this (line 41):

```
return Activities.find({user: id}, {sort: {timeStamp: -1}, limit:40});
```

One document in the activities collection looks like this:

```
{
    "user" : "ZJrgYm34rR92zg6z7",
    "type" : "editArg",
    "debId" : "wtziFDS4bB3CCkNLo",
    "argId" : "YAnjh2Pu6QESzHQLH",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2014-09-12T22:10:29.586Z"),
    "_id" : "sEDDreehonp67haDg"
}
```

When I run the query done in line 41 in mongo shell, I get the following error:

```
error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: timeStamp", "code" : 13097 }
```

I don't really why this is though. Can you help me there as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you are passing an integer to `skip` and `limit`. Use `parseInt()` if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You have a document on your website that does not match your `check` validation.

The validation you have is in `app/server/publications.js:41`

So the attribute in question exists in some way like `Match.optional(Match.oneOf(xx))` but the document's attribute is neither of the values in `Match.oneOf`

You would have to go through your documents for the collection causing this and remove or correct the attribute causing this to match your `check` statement.

### Update for your updated question.

You're running Meteor commands in the `meteor mongo`/mongo shell. The error you get is unrelated to the problem in Meteor, to sort in the mongo shell you would do `activities.find(..).sort()`, instead of `activities.find(.., { sort : {..})`. This is unrelated to the issue

The issue is most-likely that your `id` is not actually a string. Its supposed to be `sEDDreehonp67haDg` for the document you're looking for. You might want to use the debugger to see what it actually is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not have a check statement in my publication. Line 41 is a MongoDB.find() call. I added my publication code in the question.

Comment: @fritzi2000 I'd recommend you check `id` it may not be a string or mongodb id object.

Comment: I'll check that. Meanwhile, I have found out that line 41 at the time this error occurred apparently line 41 was this: Arguments.find({flagged: {$gte: 5}}, {limit: limit})

This however does not yield any error when I run it in robomongo

Comment: I ran the command in robomongo with a string as id and I got that exact same error. The problem seems to be the sorting.

Comment: @fritzi2000 It may not be likely that its this. The command you use in Meteor does not operate the same way as in the mongo console. The second option (projections) `xx.find(query, projections)` under the mongo console which is `options` in Meteor, which is why you see the error unsupported projection option. The commands aren't exactly interoperable

Comment: I have the same issue when I use '''Meteor.users.find({'services.facebook.id': {$in: facebookFriendsIds}}, {fields: '_id', multi: true});''', But it works if I use '''Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: userIds}}, {fields: '_id', multi: true});'''.

Comment: @Yong, why are you using `multi` in a find query? also check that facebookFriendIds is an array of strings/objectids and not something else

Comment: I got this error when I passed in a string rather than a number into either "limit" or "skip" of .find() - just convert and see if that fixes it. (Quick javascript convert number trick : "string" *1)

Comment: I also encountered this error when I subscribed to a collection twice in the same scope.

Comment: I got this on the client when I used limit. Without limit, the problem goes away

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `limit` in client-side find queries. Removing `limit` from my query solves the problem. If you're looking for pagination, then you can either manually roll your own by passing a parameter to your Activities publication so that the limit is added to the server-side query along with an offset. There is also [this pagination package](https://github.com/egtann/meteor-pagination).

Comment: Interesting though that I only had this occur when testing on iOS (8.x) and not on Android (5.1.x) within Cordova