# Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation

Tags: mongodb, meteor, match

I am trying to retrive limited data from mongodb collection with this command.

```js
Collection.find({
    'to': {
        '$in': ['user1@email.com', 'user2@test.com']
    },
    'from': {
        '$in': ['user1@email.com', 'user2@test.com']
    }
}, {
    sort: {
        createdAt: 1
    },
    skip: 0,
    limit: 10
}).fetch();
```

But getting error:
Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation

This error only appears in ios. Not in browser or android. I have used Meteor and mongodb in this application.This is client side call.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's the full error message and where's it coming from?

Comment: It is coming from mongo.js  but it solved after downgrade angularjs to 1.0.7

Comment: There were big updates in the latest version of angular meteor. That would be your problem. Don't know exactly where though. Read the upgrade guide

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to solve that issue.                                                      Same Issue  Ref link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104937/meteor-match-error-failed-match-oneof-or-match-optional-validation-websocket

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue yesterday in Meteor 1.2 using meteor angular 1.3

Things.find({},{limit:4}) blows with this same message on the emulator android. and also on the browser sometimes...

Here is a solution that works for me:

- create a new meteor project. meteor create newPrj
- cd newPrj
- remove newPrj files (html, css, js)
- copy all files and folders from your original project except .meteor directory in the new one.
- copy the .meteor/package.js from your original project and copy it in the new one, same destination.
- meteor add-platform android
- then run meteor. meteor will reinstall all packages and rebuild your app.

Update: I compared the .meteor/versions in the new project with the old one.
-pbastowski:angular-babel@1.0.8
+pbastowski:angular-babel@1.0.9

so just update your babel...